# unable to do validations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a contact us page

```
    class ContactPagesController < ApplicationController

    def new
    @contact_page =  ContactPage.new
     end

     def create


      @contact_page = ContactPage.new(contact_page_params)

      if    @contact_page.save
          flash[:notice]="details saved successfully"
     redirect_to contact_pages_path
     else
    flash[:notice]="details not saved"
    redirect_to contact_pages_path
      end
    #  if @contact_page.errors.any?
    # flash[:notice]="there are errors"
     # end
    end

       private
      def contact_page_params
      params.require(:contact_page).permit( :first_name, :last_name, :email,    :phone, :do_you_have_land, :moving_time_frame, :financing, :to$
       end
       end
```

and my model

```
    class ContactPage < ApplicationRecord
    validates :email, presence: true
    end
```

and the view

```
      new.html.erb

      <%= form_for @contact_page, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', multipart: true } do |f| %>
      <% if @contact_page.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
      <h3>

        <%= pluralize(@contact_page.errors.count, "error") %>
        prohibited this employee from being saved:
      </h3>
      <ul>
        <% @contact_page.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li>
            <%= message %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="control-group">
   <%= f.label :First_Name, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
     <%= f.text_field :first_name, :class => 'text_field' %>
   </div>
   </div>
  <div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :Email, :class => 'control-label' %>
   <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'text_field' %>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :How_can_we_assist_you, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
  <%= f.text_field :assist_you, :class => 'text_field' %>
  </div>
  </div>




 <div class="form-actions">
 <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>

 </div>
 <% end %>
```

If all the fields are filled the data is being saved into the database.If email is left blank  data is also not being saved inside the database(due to validation), but the error message is also not rendering . The @contact_page.errors.any? inside the view page is being ignored for some reason.I am expecting an error "email can't be blank" on the top of the form.

why the save action is not triggering the validation errors?

my routes for contact page

```
       get 'contact_pages' => 'contact_pages#new', :as => 'contact_pages'
       post 'contact_pages' => 'contact_pages#create'
```

Need help in what I have gone wrong.Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you just open `rails console` and try `ContactPage.create!`, see if you are getting the error message or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SaveController < ApplicationController

         def new
           @contact_page =  ContactPage.new
         end 

    def create
        if    
           @contact_page.save
           flash[:notice]="Successfuly stored"
           redirect_to contact_pages_path
        else
           flash[:notice]="please check your inputs"
           render :new
        end
    end
end
```

In View: -

```
 <% if notice  %>
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <%= notice %>
            </div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should user render on error not redirect

```
def create
    @contact_page = ContactPage.new(contact_page_params)

    if    
       @contact_page.save
       flash[:notice]="details saved successfully"
       redirect_to contact_pages_path
    else
       flash[:notice]="details not saved"
       render :new
    end
end
```